# use pagination in laravel api resource in laravel

Tags: laravel, pagination

I want to use pagination after getting my data from api resource
But the server responds:

```
 Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::pagination does not exist.
```

```
  public function index(Request $request )
    {
        $perPage=$request->per_page;
        return response()->json(['user'=>UserResource::collection(User::with('roles')->get()->pagination($perPage))],200);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to call paginate on get function

Just

```
public function index(Request $request ) {
    $perPage=$request->per_page;
    return response()->json(['user'=>UserResource::collection(User::with('roles')->pagination($perPage))],200);
}
```

Even Better

```
public function index(Request $request ) {
    $perPage=$request->per_page;
    return new UserCollection(User::with('roles')->paginate($perPage));
}
```

Comment: Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::pagination()

Answer (score 0):

```
        return response()->json(['user'=>UserResource::collection(User::paginate($perPage))],200);
```

this is worked correctly !
100% ok